# JavaScript regex convert string into object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string looks like this:

```
var str = "
a:aaa
b:bbb"
```

What is the best way to turn this string into JavaScript object like this?

```
{a:"aaa", b:"bbb"}
```

Comment: First convert it to an associative array, then call `json_encode()` to convert it to Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map/reduce solution:

```js
var str = "\na:aaa\nb:bbb"

var obj = str
        // split into lines
        .split("\n")
        // only keep lines with a ':'
        .filter(function(x) { return x.indexOf(':') !== -1; })
        // At this point we have Array [ "a:aaa", "b:bbb" ]
        // foreach line, split into key and value, and put 
        // in an array
        .map(function(line) { return line.split(':'); })
        // At this point we have Array[['a', 'aaa'], ['b', 'bbb']]
        // use reduce: use an empty object as the accumulator
        // and add keys/values sequentially
        .reduce(function(acc, el) { acc[el[0]] = el[1]; return acc }, {});
        
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the best way, but *a* way:

```js
console.log(
  "a:aaa\nb:bbb".split('\n').reduce(
    (obj, line) => {
      const [key, val] = line.split(':');
      obj[key] = val;
      return obj;
    },
    {}
  )
);
```

Split lines by line break, iterate over each line, split it on `:` and add it to an object.

Comment: Thanks to all. You guys are very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern `^([^:]):(.*)$` with the global `g` and the multiline `m` flag. This pattern requires every line to be in the format `x:y` whereas `x` cannot contain a colon and there has to be at least one colon.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('element').textContent;
var regex = /^([^:]):(.*)$/gm;

var match = regex.exec(text);
var object = {};
while(match != null) {
  object[match[1]] = match[2];
  match = regex.exec(text);
}

console.log(object);
```

```html
<pre id="element">
a:aaa
b:bbb
</pre>
```